# Regex negative lookbehind to escape period/dot

Tags: java, regex

I had been struggling to find out a regex pattern that would escape `"."` if a escape char is found before it. Negative lookbehind was promising but I suppose it doesn't work for `"."` as with below syntax

```
String test = "hostname.domain.com/abc/def/v1.8/ghi"
```

In above example, string needs to be split by `"."` , but I need to escape the v1.8 so that v1 and 8 are not treated as different array elements in the URI part.

```
String test = "hostname.domain.com/abc/def/v1\\.8/ghi"
test.split("(?!\\\\).");
```

The expected output {"hostname","domain","com/abc/def/v1.8/ghi"} . The URI context path should not be split by "." if it carries any "." it would just for representing version.

The above negative lookbehind syntax works for other char's like `-`, but doesn't work for `"."`. I assume the escape character needs to be different, but adding other escape chars might cause issue in further processing of the string as the input is of URI type and don't want any reserved/special chars in URI to be used as char to prepend for this. Any thoughts/help from anyone is appreciated.

Comment: There is no way that pattern worked for you. `(?!\\\\)` is a negative **lookahead**, and the `.` is not escaped, so it matches all characters.

Comment: So, what is `"v1\\.8/ghi"`? Is that a real string? Will you ever have `\.`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use this negative lookahead regex:

```
(?!\\\\)(?:^|.)\\.
```

OR Using negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!\\\\)\\.
```

Online Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/Sqa2P7A6dR and http://www.rubular.com/r/xgE7onrwzX

Comment: How to remove the slash using negative lookbehind? For example, split `aaa.bbb\.ccc` as `[aaa, bbb.ccc]`.

Comment: Splitting and replacement are 2 different operations so you can split by `(?<!\\\\)\\.` but will need to replace backslash later from generated array.

Comment: How to ignore escaped slash using negative lookbehind? For example, split `aaa.bbb\\.ccc` as `[aaa, bbb\\, ccc]`.

Comment: I mean, ignore the dot only if the slash is not escaped. For example, split `aaa.bbb\\.ccc` as `[aaa, bbb\\, ccc]` and `aaa.bbb\.ccc` as `[aaa, bbb\.ccc]`.

Comment: In your demo, `aaa\\.bbb\.ccc` is split as `[aaa, bbb\.ccc]` while it should be split as `[aaa\\, bbb\.ccc]`.

Comment: That site seems specific to Javascript. In Java, the result is different.

Answer (score 4):

Why use regex..Use [URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class

```
URL url=new URL(yourURL);
url.getPath();//abc/def/v1.8/ghi
url.getPort();//-1 in your case
url.getHost();//hostname.domain.com
```

You can now split the hostname with `.`

Comment: Thanks for the input, but even though the input is in URI format, its not going be parsed as URI in the flow. The logic splits the context path and creates a service name string for restful URI. The other end that stores service name will NOT parse the string as URI. Thanks for the time

Answer (score 1):

To avoid multiple use of escape characters in the regex string (one level of escaping is removed by the Java compiler; the other level is removed by the regex engine) it is possible to "escape" characters by enclosing them in square brackets. For example, `\\\\.` would become a more readable `[.]`.

In your case, you could tell Java not to use a dot that is between two digits, because it's a decimal separator:

```
String test = "hostname.domain.com/abc/def/v1.8/ghi";
for (String s : test.split("(?<!\\d)[.](?!\\d)")) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/ZZJFSq).

Answer (score 1):

try this expr

```
 String[] s = "hostname.domain.com/abc/def/v1.8/ghi".split("(?<!/.{0,99})\\.");
```